# How to make json jackson faster?

Tags: java, json, jackson

this line of code takes about 2 seconds to execute!

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

since two seconds is a life time when it comes to computing, is there any way to make jackson respond faster?

i am using :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: You can't just _make_ it faster. But consider upgrading to Jackson 2.

Comment: use a singleton instance

Comment: is there any difference between fasterxml and codehaus? they both have jackson

Comment: There's tons of differences. You can read the changelog. Your best solution is to do what @RC suggested.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the last version in http://www.mvnrepository.com/ is 1.9.13

Comment: They are different projects, different artifacts. It's [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core).

Comment: if they are different projects i cant just change from codehaus to fasterxml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Jackson you are using is an older version, consider upgrading to Jackson 2.0. There may be a bit of efforts involved (depends on what APIs you are using), but any new features and performance enhancements will likely to be 2.x only. Have a look at [Jackson Release: 2.0](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonRelease20) for more information and upgrade notes.

As for `ObjectMapper`, this is what [Jackson Best Practices: Performance](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonBestPracticesPerformance) says:

> [ObjectMapper](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/ObjectMapper): object mappers cache serializers and deserializers that are created first time handler is needed for given type (or more precisely, mapper holds a reference to Provider objects that do). If you do not reuse mappers, new serializers and deserializers need to be created each time: and these are expensive operations due to amount of introspection and annotation processing involved.

What is the platform you are running on, mobile perhaps? On my 3+ year old laptop creating an instance takes less than half a second.

If performance is a concern and your JSON is not too complex, consider using Jackson's streaming API (that's the real power of Jackson) to parse the JSON data yourself, it will be an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: platform is a laptop corei7 8gb ram. the json is a bit complex and there are several layers of inheritance and abstractions involved

Comment: @dave I find it hard to believe `new ObjectMapper()` would take 2 seconds on such a powerful machine, mine is only a Core 2 Duo and it takes about 400 ms. Can you measure again?

Comment: The link you posted was unpublished. Here is an archived version: https://web.archive.org/web/20170901052130/http://wiki.fasterxml.com:80/JacksonBestPracticesPerformance